# UserControl Event is Not Firing If control loads on a click event

Tags: asp.net

I am loading a user control on my default page. Deafult page having a button on which click i am loading The UserControl.

But Using the above the events of the usercontrol are not firing.

If I load control on Deafult page load then the Usercontrol events are working fine..

So what is wrong with loading the control with the click event.

Comment: hard to figure out from your question what is the problem. give us the code..

Comment: You might find your life a lot simpler if you just put the markup for your user control straight on your page and just toggle the `Visible` attribute on the button click. Or if you needs lots of copies of the control, use a `Repeater`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create dynamic controls then as you have noticed you need to re-create them when you post back the page.

See [this guide](http://www.stev.org/post/2011/03/02/ASPNET-Dynamic-Controls.aspx) for details or this old but still [relevant article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx)